Microsoft Entra SSO integration with AWS IAM Identity Center, where AWS is the Identity Source
I spent a lot of time looking for the intergation between AWS and Entra, where AWS is the identity source. I want AWS ITAM Identity Center to manage users and Entra to have SAML federation with AWS, so that users from AWS are provisioned automatically to Entra.
So far I only found the following documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/saas-apps/aws-single-sign-on-tutorial#test-sso
But it only describes a scenario where Entra is the source of Identity. Is it even possible to configure AWS as a source of identity? I was not able to find the right documentation on the AWS side or anywhere in the Internet.
